# Recommended Datastax Drivers version to connect to Cassandra Version 4.0

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

Currently we are using Java Datastax Drivers Version 3.7.2 to connect to Open source Apache Cassandra Version 3.11.9.

We are planning on to upgrade to Open Source Apache Cassandra Version 4 , Can someone please let me know what are the recommended Java Datastax Drivers version to connect to Cassandra Version 4. I see in this article Datastax had mentioned that Datastax Drivers Version 3.11 is partially compatible with Cassandra Version 4.X and did not have much information on what they mean about partially compatible?

https://docs.datastax.com/en/driver-matrix/docs/java-drivers.html

Answer (score 2):

First, [Apache Cassandra® 4.1 is already released last Dec](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/blog/Cassandra-4.1-is-here.html) and you may want to look at upgrading to that as opposed to 4.0.x.

Next, partially compatible is also explained in the docs section as,

> ^4^ Limited to the Cassandra 3.x and 2.2.x API.

Also, I'm taking excerpts from [the mailing list discussions](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/g/java-driver-user/c/lMlnbgVG8sQ/m/Hgrij64uCgAJ) here.

> Neither the 4.x nor the 3.x Java drivers are in maintenance mode at the moment. It is very much true that any new Java driver features will be developed on the 4.x branch and in general will not be ported to 3.x.  3.x will continue to receive CVE and other critical bug fixes but as mentioned there are no plans for this branch to receive any new features.  It's not completely impossible that a specific feature or two might make it's way to 3.x on a case-by-case basis but if you're planning for the future with 3.x you should do so with the expectation that it will receive no new features.

&

> Having said that, I would strongly recommend and encourage you to upgrade to the [3.11.3 version of the java driver (released on Sep 20, 2022)](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/tree/3.x/changelog#3113) which is directly binary compatible with the version that you're using today, [3.7.2 (released on Jul 10, 2019)](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/g/java-driver-user/c/_ZYiQ326Y2U/m/VQRBJ5C-CAAJ), to leverage features and fixes (including many CVE patches). In addition, I would also suggest you to sketch out a plan to [upgrade your apps to 4.x driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/upgrade_guide/) or look into modernizing to [interact with your Apache Cassandra®/DSE®/Astra DB® cluster via the Stargate® APIs](https://stargate.io/docs/latest/develop/developing.html).